# Is a Samba share faster using a private IP rather than public IP?

Tags: networking

I have some Samba shares on an Ubuntu server. On the Mac clients, I can "Connect to a server" through its private IP or its public IP. I would like to use the public IP so the configuration is the same when I am away from the office. However, when in the office, will using the public IP be slower than using the private one?

Comment: Don't connect via an IP at all.  Connect by a DNS name, that you server as having the private IP when hosts are on the inside, and the public IP when hosts are on the outside.  Though, you really shouldn't have SMB open to the Internet.  That is a recipe for badness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, the answer is no, there is no inherent difference between how a private IP (192.168.x.x, for example) is handled vs a public IP address. There are some specifics that you would need to provide for us to be able to truly answer the question though:

The meat and potatoes is this: If your client can get to the server without traversing a slower link then there should be no appreciable difference between the two. If your public IP network is only used on 100mbit equipment, but your private IP network uses all gigabit, then yes, you'll see a difference.